# Checking the new permission model

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-appcompat

I am checking my app's permissions against the new permission model on Android 6.0

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

targetting the app on API23 , using Appcompatv7-r23, installing the signed app via adb on emulator device Android 6.0 and running it: 
at runtime nothing new happens, the app works well as before API 23, and it seems that all those permissions are automatically granted on install time.

I inserted `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` for RECORD_AUDIO permission and it soon returns "PERMISSION_GRANTED".

Is it possible that those three permissions are retained as not dangerous by the new permission model?
Is mine a valid test?

Comment: "targetting the app on API23" -- do you mean that your `targetSdkVersion` is set to 23?

Comment: yes, android:targetSdkVersion="23". And project build target on API23.

Comment: Gpack, not possible for storage permission , Go to setting --> App --> see what all permission your app have

Comment: If you have not done so already, do a full uninstall and reinstall, and see what happens.

Comment: Reinstalled yet many times.

Comment: in the settings all permission are granted, without never triggering any permission dialog

Comment: this is strange !! using Nexus 5 device where it is working perfectly OK.

Comment: You can use this code https://gist.github.com/Elshad/9fde7f8908207aa2916c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My test was not valid because emulator was not running on API23 platform, although I have chosen API23 on device's definition.

Comment: @OmarElDon How can your comment be of any help?

Comment: @Kyle Mar it's there just to notify others, this answer is not helpful at all... he contradicted his own question, the question itself is ambigious... maybe he wanted some upvotes instead of deleting his question

Answer (score 0):

It is still in dangerous category and not granted at install for those app, targeting Android M

Comment: Did you try on emulator with Appcompatv7-r23?